# Can't get a Lambda function to send back information

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I just got my first Lambda function written, but it does not work at this point.
I tried a number of variations in the code; partly following what I could think of and partly following what I could come across on the net; but all failed.

I want the Lambda function to listUsers in a UserPool and get an email for a given sub passed as parameter.

Here is the Swift function making the call to the Lambda function:

```
func getLambdaInfo() {
    let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default(),
    jsonObject:[String: Any] =  ["sub" : "MY-USER-SUB"]

    lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("myLambdaFunc", jsonObject: jsonObject)
        .continueWith(block: {
            (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
            if( task.error != nil) {
                print("Error: \(task.error!)")
                return nil
            }

            print("\(#function) ---- WE ARE HERE!!!!")

            // Handle response in task.result:
            if let JSONDictionary = task.result as? NSDictionary {
                print("Result: \(JSONDictionary)")
            }

            return nil
        })
}
```

Here is the Lambda function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');

exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    var params = {
        UserPoolId: 'MY-POOL-ID',
        AttributesToGet: ['email'],
        Limit: '2'
    };

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      // How can I get this data sent in the response is probably the issue ??
    });

    const response = {
        inBound: event.sub,
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!')
    };

    return response;
}
```

Here is what can be seen in the Xcode debugging console:

```
getLambdaInfo() ---- WE ARE HERE!!!!
Result: {
    body = "\"Hello from Lambda!\"";
    inBound = "MY-USER-SUB";
    statusCode = 200;
}
```

I hope someone with more AWSLambda than me will be able to give me some hints concerning the changes I need to make in my code to get the result (email address) I want (into my Swift getLambdaInfo()).

Comment: FYI the issue here is not so much your understanding of AWS Lambda as it is of asynchronous JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your `return` statement in the callback of `listUsers`:

```js
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    // return a 500 error ?
  }
  else {
    console.log(data);
    const response = {
      inBound: event.sub,
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    return response;
  }
});
```

Since you're using the `async` pattern you can also do:

```js
try {
  const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params).promise() // note the await and .promise() here
  const response = {
    inBound: event.sub,
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
  return response;
} catch (err) {
 // do something with err
}
```

Otherwise your Lambda function returns before your callback gets executed (async nature of JavaScript).

Comment: It is still not completely working. But your answer gave me a good help to move forward.

Comment: When running inside Lambda or locally? This is not related to your code, it means the aws-sdk cannot find credentials have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Comment: OK. I will take a look. I was suspecting this was because I did not set the right permission so that my lambda function could run listUsers. And I am not even sure how I need to set the permissions for that. I mean I am not sure what kind of permissions I  need.

Comment: I must say I don't know what kind of credential it is talking about here. As far as I can tell I have set all the necessary permissions. And my function seems to have the right permissions inside lambda ...